# Naming an Image as a Navigation Bar Name

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uinavigationcontroller

instead of having the name of the view to show up in the middle of the navigation bar, for an image to show up there?
Here's my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"More", @"More Options");

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Map", @"About", nil];
self.moreArray = array;
[array release];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [titleView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView) property of the `navigationItem` like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"whatever.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,224, 44);
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Comment: You are welcome! If you are satisfied with my answer please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it :)